# Is it possible to have 2 workspaces on the same screen

Tags: windows, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [1 PC, 2 consoles (as in 2 monitors, keyboards and mice)](https://superuser.com/questions/253370/1-pc-2-consoles-as-in-2-monitors-keyboards-and-mice)

Is it possible to divide the screen into 2 work-spaces, each with its own keyboard and mouse , mouse pointer etc.

Each workspace must independent of the other  and must act as if it is an another computer.

I should also be able to ping the other Work-area.

[OS: Windows XP or Windows 7]

[image]

Comment: @techie007: Will I be able to ping both consoles using BeTwin VS ?

Comment: What do you mean by divide? If you want to share the desktop look into VNC. If you want to support multiple independent desktops in Windows for different users simultaneously then there's Windows Remote Desktop Service but this only available in server versions of Windows. While client versions of Windows have Remote Desktop Service, it's only for Fast User Switching and doesn't allow multiple remote desktops like Windows Server's Terminal Services.

Comment: @techie007: The duplicate does not apply - only one monitor here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, setup a virtual machine and assign it a separate keyboard and mouse. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/12284/dedicated-mouse-and-keyboard-for-a-virtual-machine-is-it-possible) for details.

Comment: Can I get different ip like in the image in my question ?

Comment: Yes, your VM can have a different IP, but with VMs you will have to use private IPs - you can do something like 192.168.1.100 for the host and 192.168.1.101 for the VM.

Comment: That sounds awesome , can you tell me which VM will suit me ?

Comment: VirtualBox is always a good bet.

Comment: Can you tell me the steps to setting up a private IP in VirtualBox ?

Comment: Look here for network configuration for virtual box: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of. I would suggest a second monitor or a KVM switch.

Comment: What is a KVM switch

Comment: Keyboard Video Mouse. It lets multiple computers share one keyboard, monitor and mouse set. Some will let you share audio as well.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [WinSplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/) or [Gridvista](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Acer-Gridvista.shtml), both are free.

However, as they are on the same computer, ping does not apply.

[image]